# How can I make a font like Apple Color Emoji.ttf that uses color bitmap images?

Tags: ios, fonts, emoji

I want to make a color bitmap font with PNG images in the same format as `Apple Color Emoji.ttf` so that it can be used in iOS apps. But I can't find any references. Is it possible? If so, how to?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but might be somewhat helpful: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638335

Answer (score 0):

Version 3 of [TypeTool](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/) added this feature.  Use that tool to create a TTF file with the icons you want.

Once you create your TTF file, follow [these instructions](http://blog.beefyapps.com/?p=316) to embed your font in the app.

Comment: Are you sure it keeps colored images in the generated font? Did you make any such font with it? If so, can you show me a sample font? Thanks.

Comment: TypeTool does not support embedding color bitmaps like the Apple Color Emoji font. Haven't found any GUI that does yet.